# Let V denote the Klein 4-group. Show that $\text{Aut} (V)$ is isomorphic to $S_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra

After a week in my Abstract Algebra class, the professor proposed this as a problem. I'm not entirely sure where to begin. $ V = \{ e, \tau, \tau_1, \tau_2 \}$, so I'm not sure exactly what is meant by $\text{Aut} (V)$. Is it simply saying that the only way to have an automorphism on $V$ is to rearrange the order of the elements of $V$ and therefore $\text{Aut} (V) \cong S_3$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any automorphism $\phi$ of $V$ sends its identity element $e$ to itself. What is interesting is the way that $\phi$ rearranges the other three elements. The claim here is that any of the six possible bijections from $\tau, \tau_1, \tau_2$ to itself is in fact a group automorphism of $V$. This will give an isomorphism from $\operatorname{Aut}(V) \cong S_3$ that sends an automorphism $\phi \in \operatorname{Aut}(V)$ to its corresponding permutation of the three elements $\tau, \tau_1, \tau_2$.

Comment: Why is it $\operatorname{Aut}(V) \cong S_4$ not $\operatorname{Aut}(V) \cong S_3$?

Comment: Because I'm an idiot who makes mistakes. Sorry.

Comment: Could you formally write that $\forall \Gamma (\phi), \exists ! \sigma(S_3) : \sigma(S_3) \cong \Gamma(\phi)$?, where $\Gamma$ is the isomorphism and $\sigma$ is an arbitrary permutation

Answer (score 3):

There are three elements of order $2$ in $V$. Identity element must go to identity element by any automorphism, and you can permute *in any way* the elements of order $2$, so $Aut(V)=S_3$.

Of course, you need to check that any permutation gives you an automorphism. It is obviously bijective, and is very easy to check directly that any such permutation preserves the group law.

Comment: it involves some work, which is hairy